# Calculating Accrued Interest with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate the amount of interest that would've accrued during a period of time. I have the starting DataFrame as below

```
MONTH_BEG_D NO_OF_DAYS  RATE
1/10/2017   31          5.22
1/11/2017   30          5.22
1/12/2017   31          5.22
1/1/2018    31          3.5
1/2/2018    28          3.5
1/3/2018    31          3.5
```

If the starting value is 20, I would like the outcome to be:

```
FORMULA: INTEREST = (PRINCIPAL_A * RATE * NO_OF_DAYS) / 36500

PRINCIPAL_A MONTH_BEG_D RATE    NO_OF_DAYS      INTEREST        NEW_BALANCE
20          1/10/2017   5.22    31              0.08866849      20.08866849
20.08866849 1/11/2017   5.22    30              0.08618864      20.17485713
20.17485713 1/12/2017   5.22    31              0.08944371      20.26430084
20.26430084 1/1/2018    3.5     31              0.06023772      20.32453856
20.32453856 1/2/2018    3.5     28              0.05456999      20.37910855
```

Just to explain, the 36500 is from 365 days of the year for `NO_OF_DAYS` and the 0.01 multiplier for `RATE`. I can easily add/modify columns for these 2 variables so this is no problem. My problem lies in how I can carry the `NEW_BALANCE` over as the next month's `PRINCIPAL_A`

This is basically a `cumprod` between each column with a `cumsum` between each row. Is there an easier way of doing this while avoiding loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, not the cleanest solution but it does what you require!

```
#ENSURE TO IMPORT NUMPY LIBRARY.
import numpy as np

#INCREASE PRECISION OUTPUT.
pd.options.display.precision = 7

#INSERT PRINCIPAL_A COLUMN WITH NULL VALUE, LATER TO SET THE INITIAL VALUE.
df.insert(0, 'PRINCIPAL_A', np.nan)

#SET INITIAL VALUE AS 20 IN FIRST ROW ONLY.
df.iloc[0:1, 0] = 20

#LOOP OVER DATAFRAME FOR ROLL-OVER.
for row in range(1, len(df)):
    df['INTEREST'] = (df['PRINCIPAL_A'] * df['RATE'] * df['NO_OF_DAYS']) / 36500
    df['NEW_BALANCE'] = df['PRINCIPAL_A'] + df['INTEREST']
    df.iloc[row : row+1]['PRINCIPAL_A'] = df['NEW_BALANCE'].shift(1) #ROLL-OVER NEW BALANCE USING PANDAS SHIFT.
```

There is the output (slightly different than yours due to rounding) :

```
    PRINCIPAL_A MONTH_BEG_D NO_OF_DAYS  RATE    INTEREST    NEW_BALANCE
0   20.0000000  01/10/2017  31          5.22    0.0886685   20.0886685
1   20.0886685  01/11/2017  30          5.22    0.0861886   20.1748571
2   20.1748571  01/12/2017  31          5.22    0.0894437   20.2643008
3   20.2643008  01/01/2018  31          3.50    0.0602377   20.3245386
4   20.3245386  01/02/2018  28          3.50    0.0545700   20.3791086
5   20.3791086  01/03/2018  31          3.50    NaN         NaN
```